# Creating search form that will query SQL database and display results on a custom block

Tags: sql-server, drupal, bootstrap-4, drupal-8

I am a new to **Drupal** and have learnt about custom blocks.

Basically, I am trying to `create a search page` where on the left column will have all the `filter/search criteria`.

On the right column the results will be displayed in a specified format in a custom block. Not sure where to start on this work.

I have my back end ready with **all the parameters** going in correctly and results are displayed out of a **stored procedure**.

Not sure about how to wire up the front end filter criteria fields with **backend SQL parameters**.

I am using **Drupal 8 - bootstrap** theme custom blocks to design the page and SQL server **(using SSMS tool) backend** to achieve this. Any guide on how to start this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually Drupal is build for less code and less custom code writing
All the functionality about exposing form for filters and result and results formatting are available in views module where you can expose filters and result formats as you need.

First lessen about Drupal was for me to avoid custom code until you  did not find any Drupal solution.

and in your case you can achieve your all needs with only views.
[Documentation for the Drupal 8 core Views module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views) Here will find some views initial steps 
I hope this helps you
Thanks